# How to recover an accidentally deleted new pages document

Tags: pages

I accidentally clicked "delete" (clicked too fast thinking it was cancel) on the save new document prompt when exiting Pages. After one bad click, the file is completely gone, with no clear way to undo the mistake.

How can I recover (some version) of this lost document?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that might have done this, here is my solution:

I created another new document with a unique string and searched spotlight to find the directory where autosaved Pages files live. With that directory open in Finder, I could use Time Machine to find the old autosaved file ("Unsaved Pages Document.pages") from an hour ago.

For me the directory was:

> ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Autosave
>   Information